# 'MovieDataContext' could not be found

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I am following the tutorial

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-(data)/creating-model-classes-with-linq-to-sql-cs.

I'm getting the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'MovieDataContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says:

> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

So add the correct using clause to bring the namespace into which this class is defined into scope:

```
using MvcApplication1.Models;
```

Comment: @niranjan n Darin i m using the namespace "MvcApplication5.Models"...no success

Comment: @niranjan kala n Darin ok i figured it out..thanks both of u fr ur help

Answer (score 0):

Check this **Listing 1 – Controllers\HomeController.cs**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication1.Models; // you have forgotten to include this
```

**Listing 1** uses a `LINQ to SQL` DataContext class (the `MovieDataContext`) to represent the `MoviesDB` database. The `MoveDataContext` class was `generated by` the `Visual Studio Object Relational Designer.`

> If you have done the work of creating the LINQ to SQL Classes then
>   just include the **using statements** as in the **listing 1**